# Capture Home, End, Page Up, and Page Down Keys from Terminal on OS X in Node?

Tags: node.js

The follow code is triggering the `data` event for most keys on the keyboard, except it is not triggering for these keys:

- Home
- End
- Page Up
- Page Down

Code:

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true); // Takes input character by character   
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('data', function(key) {
    console.log('key', key);
});
```

Anyone know why?

(Node 5.7.0 - OS X El Capitan)

Comment: I test your codes with node v5.7.0 under Window. It works well for the keys you mentioned...

Comment: @zangw confirmed, Windows works, if appears that it is just an OS X issue